# Bulk edit product names in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

for a multistore I want to edit the titles of my products... like a download a csv file and then edit fast (search and replace). And then upload.
Do you know if it’s possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out Magento's default Import/Export module? You can export/import products from `System -> Import/Export -> Import` / `System -> Import/Export -> Export`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Liam's answer, this are the steps I would take:

Go to `System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles`, then click `Add New Profile` button at top right

In Profile Information:

1. Set a Name for the Profile
2. Set Entity Type to `Products`
3. Set Direction to `Export`
4. Set Store to `Default (Admin) Values`

In File Information:

1. Set Data transfer to `Local/Remote Server`
2. Set Type to `Local Server`
3. Set File name to `your_file_name.csv`
4. Set Path to `var/export`

In Data Format:

1. Set Type to `CSV / Tab Separated`
2. Set Value Delimter to `,` (comma)
3. Set Enclosed Values to `"` (quotation)
4. Set Original Magento attribute names in first row to `Yes`
5. Set Export to `Only Mapped Fields`

In Field Mapping:

1. Click the `Add Field Mapping` button three times

(do not change values it will auto-populate in `In File` when selecting from dropdown)

2. In the first field, select `Store` from the dropdown list. We do this to ensure on a multi-store setup that the value entered is set at a global level, not a store specific one. This value should output as `admin` in your CSV
3. In the second field, select `SKU` from the dropdown list. We do this to get the SKU of our product as a reference for which product to update the name of
4. In the third field, select `name` from the dropdown list. We do this to get the current name/title of the product related to the SKU from the previous field.

These are all the fields you should need if you only want to update the `Names` of products.

Click the `Save and Continue Edit` button at the top right to save your work thus far. Once the save is complete, the page is reloaded and you will notice new tabs on the left side that are available to select.

Click the `Run Profile` tab to open the area you will run this custom export from. Once in this area, click `Run Profile in Popup` and a new tab/window will open that will be blank at first. Depending on how many products are to be included in your export and other PHP settings for your Magento directory, this may take some time to open or will show a PHP timeout if you don't have enough memory or long enough time settings enabled.

Once the export is complete, you'll see a few rows similar to a SQL query screen. One of these will give you the number of products that were included in the export.

Via Cpanel or FTP: Go to your `MAGENTO_DIRECTORY/var/export` folder and find the newly exported `.csv` from this export and download it to your computer. I prefer to use Google Docs as Microsoft Office tends to mess with CSVs and alter certain values without any prompt or warning.

Make your changes to the document and export/save again as `.csv`

At this point, you have three options:

1. Create a new import dataflow profile

   a. In `System > Import/Export > Dataflow Profiles` click `Add A New Profile`

   b. PROFILE INFORMATION: Give it a name, Entity Type - `Products`, Direction - `Import`, Store - `Default (Admin) Values`, Number of Records - `1`, Decimal Separator - `.` (period)

   c. FILE INFORMATION: Data Transfer - `Local/Remote Server`, Type - `Local Server`, File name - `your_file_name.csv`, Path - `var/import`

   d. DATA FORMAT: Type - `CSV / Tab Separated`, Value Delimeter - `,` (comma), Enclose Values In - `"` (quotation), Original Magento attribute names in first row - `Yes` (if you didn't remove them, which i strongly suggest leaving them)

   e. Click `Save and Continue Edit` button in top right. Page will reload and new tabs will be shown at left side again.

   f. Click the `Upload File` tab on left and select your `.csv` to import. Page will reload after upload is complete.

   g. Click the `Run Profile` tab on left and select your file from the dropdown list provided.

   h. Click `Run Profile in Popup` and you'll see the same process as export happen in a new tab/window with the progress showing when completed.

   i. Check your Product names in the SKUs that you adjusted to confirm the changes were made.
2. Use the default import feature in `System > Import/Export > Import`

   a. Entity Type - `Products`, Import Behavior - `Replace Existing Complex Data`, Select your file to import

   b. Click the `Check Data` button on top right and follow steps to complete import.
3. Use Magmi to import this back to the database directly. I only recommend this if you have it setup already and are familiar with Magmi's inner workings.

OPTIONAL - In Export Filters:

1. The `Name` field will allow you to filter down to only products with names that start with the contents entered in the field.
2. The `SKU` field will allow you to filter down to only products whose SKUs start with the contents entered in the field.
3. The `Type` field will allow you to select which product types to export. Leave this on `Any Type` unless you only need one type as it does not offer multi-select
4. The `Attribute Set Name` will allow you to filter down to only products whose attribute set matches the one selected from this dropdown. Again, not multi-select.
5. The `Price` and `Stock Quantity` will allow you to filter down to only products whose `Price` and/or `QTY` is between the values set.
6. The `Visibility` field will allow you filter down to only products with that specific visibility. Handy if you have Configurable and Simple products that are visible, but don't want to rename Simples that are Not Visible but are associated to Configurables.
7. The `Status` field will allow you to filter down to only products that are `Enabled` or `Disabled` - helpful if you do not plan on re-enabling currently disabled products and only want to update those that are currently enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes products can be exported as a CSV and then reimported.

**Exporting:**

1. Go to System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles -> Export All Products.
2. Under Profile Wizard -> Store choose the desired store where you will be exporting the products.
3. Under Data Transfer drop down menu choose Local/Remote Server.
4. Under Data Format make sure CSV / Tab Separated is selected for type and click Save Profile.
5. Open Run Profile tab and click Run Profile in Popup button.
6. This will save a file named export_all_products.csv under the var/export/ directory of your Magento installation.
7. Using an FTP client or CPanel File manager download this file to your local computer. You can edit it with a spreadsheet program (MS Excel, Open Office Spreadsheet) and add the products you would like to import.

**Importing:**

1. Go to the Magento administrator area and choose System -> Import/Export -> Dataflow – Profiles -> Import All Products. Select the required settings in Profile Wizard tab.
2. Then choose Upload file tab and browse for the .csv file on your computer. Save changes.
3. Once you have uploaded it, click Import All Products, then Run Profile, select the .csv file you have just uploaded from the drop-down menu and click Run Profile in Popup.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.
The problem now is that I can´t import, I have tested with Numbers, Excel... but all the times the error: Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.

Comment: Make sure that SKU is included in the exported field list before importing the products back. You should be able to customise the fields you require.